# Does InternalsVisibleToAttribute indicate a bad design smell?

Tags: c#, api-design, encapsulation

Every time I have used the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` when developing an API, it feels a bit smelly. Like the API is not being designed in a truly encapsulated way. A lot of the times this is out of time constraints - exposing the internal functionality in an elegant, encapsulated way takes time, and a lot of times only one other assembly is going to need it, making `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` seem like the correct solution.

Does `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` indicate a design smell, such as a case of refactoring gone wrong, or an indication that the two assemblies should not be separate?

Note: I understand the need to use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` for unit testing. This question does not refer to unit testing.

Comment: I've never seen this used outside of unit testing.

Comment: Could you give us a non-unit-testing example of what you're talking about?

Comment: I disagree emphatically with your note. The unit under test is the class, not the method. If you're testing private methods, either the unit is too complex for testing and should be broken down, or you're testing at too fine-grained a level and your tests are going to be brittle.

Comment: @EricStein you might be right, never personally used it for this purpose so I don't have an opinion.

Comment: @JeffBridgman here is an example for the .NET `System.Web` assembly: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical usage for `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` is when you are a component or library vendor like Microsoft and produce components for other customers. Then you probably want to create a well restricted API to your clients and do not expose more than necessary to them (because every public API method gives a potential risk for a "breaking change" later when you distribute newer versions).

To deal with this case, you can make almost every initially "public" method of your component system internal, use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` to expose the internal methods to other libs of your library system, and set only the external API methods to public.

So for this situation (besides unit testing) the usage of `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` is IMHO clearly not a code smell. For other cases - well, at least you should think twice about it before you use it, this is surely case dependent.